# how to create mat-tree and mat-table with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, treeview

I'm trying to create a file structure with expandable and collapsable file categories and mat-table rows as files.

The data array I've from a third-party API is as below.

```
[
        {
            "ID_CAT": 1,
            "ID_CAT_Parent": null,
            "CategoryPath": "Documentation",
            "ID_FIL": 2,
            "FilePath": "/home/Octopus/Files/uploads/2_WhitePaper_Why-do-I-have-to-use-Interoperability-Matrix-Management.pdf",
            "Name": "2_WhitePaper_Why-do-I-have-to-use-Interoperability-Matrix-Management.pdf",
            "Type": "application/pdf",
            "Size": 362139,
            "Abstract_en": "Interoperability Matrix Management",
            "Description_en": "White Paper Series (2/6): Why do I have to use Interoperability Matrix Management",
            "Comment": null
        },
        {
            "ID_CAT": 2,
            "ID_CAT_Parent": 1,
            "CategoryPath": "Documentation > KnowledgeRiver",
            "ID_FIL": 2,
            "FilePath": "/home/Octopus/Files/uploads/2_WhitePaper_Why-do-I-have-to-use-Interoperability-Matrix-Management.pdf",
            "Name": "2_WhitePaper_Why-do-I-have-to-use-Interoperability-Matrix-Management.pdf",
            "Type": "application/pdf",
            "Size": 362139,
            "Abstract_en": "Interoperability Matrix Management",
            "Description_en": "White Paper Series (2/6): Why do I have to use Interoperability Matrix Management",
            "Comment": null
        },
        {
            "ID_CAT": 3,
            "ID_CAT_Parent": 2,
            "CategoryPath": "Documentation > KnowledgeRiver > Manual",
            "ID_FIL": 7,
            "FilePath": "/home/Octopus/Files/uploads/DC360Octopus-Configuration-Collection-Utility.pdf",
            "Name": "DC360Octopus-Configuration-Collection-Utility.pdf",
            "Type": "application/pdf",
            "Size": 1079488,
            "Abstract_en": "DC360Octopus Data Collector",
            "Description_en": "DC360Octopus Data Collector: How to",
            "Comment": null
        },
        {
            "ID_CAT": 4,
            "ID_CAT_Parent": 2,
            "CategoryPath": "Documentation > KnowledgeRiver > White Paper",
            "ID_FIL": 1,
            "FilePath": "/home/Octopus/Files/uploads/1_WhitePaper_Why-do-I-have-to-use-Support-Package-Management.pdf",
            "Name": "1_WhitePaper_Why-do-I-have-to-use-Support-Package-Management.pdf",
            "Type": "application/pdf",
            "Size": 2166701,
            "Abstract_en": "Support Package Management",
            "Description_en": "White Paper Series (1/6): Why do I have to use Support Package Management",
            "Comment": null
        },
        {
            "ID_CAT": 4,
            "ID_CAT_Parent": 2,
            "CategoryPath": "Documentation > KnowledgeRiver > White Paper",
            "ID_FIL": 2,
            "FilePath": "/home/Octopus/Files/uploads/2_WhitePaper_Why-do-I-have-to-use-Interoperability-Matrix-Management.pdf",
            "Name": "2_WhitePaper_Why-do-I-have-to-use-Interoperability-Matrix-Management.pdf",
            "Type": "application/pdf",
            "Size": 362139,
            "Abstract_en": "Interoperability Matrix Management",
            "Description_en": "White Paper Series (2/6): Why do I have to use Interoperability Matrix Management",
            "Comment": null
        },
        {
            "ID_CAT": 4,
            "ID_CAT_Parent": 2,
            "CategoryPath": "Documentation > KnowledgeRiver > White Paper",
            "ID_FIL": 3,
            "FilePath": "/home/Octopus/Files/uploads/3_WhitePaper_Why-do-I-have-to-conduct-an-IT-Management-Assessment.pdf",
            "Name": "3_WhitePaper_Why-do-I-have-to-conduct-an-IT-Management-Assessment.pdf",
            "Type": "application/pdf",
            "Size": 342987,
            "Abstract_en": "IT Management Assessment",
            "Description_en": "White Paper Series (3/6): Why do I have to conduct an IT Management Assessment",
            "Comment": null
        },
        {
            "ID_CAT": 4,
            "ID_CAT_Parent": 2,
            "CategoryPath": "Documentation > KnowledgeRiver > White Paper",
            "ID_FIL": 4,
            "FilePath": "/home/Octopus/Files/uploads/4_WhitePaper_How-to-setup-a-data-center-monitoring-environment.pdf",
            "Name": "4_WhitePaper_How-to-setup-a-data-center-monitoring-environment.pdf",
            "Type": "application/pdf",
            "Size": 754889,
            "Abstract_en": "Data Center Monitoring Environment",
            "Description_en": "White Paper Series (4/6): How to setup a data center monitoring environment",
            "Comment": null
        },
        {
            "ID_CAT": 4,
            "ID_CAT_Parent": 2,
            "CategoryPath": "Documentation > KnowledgeRiver > White Paper",
            "ID_FIL": 5,
            "FilePath": "/home/Octopus/Files/uploads/5_WhitePaper_How-to-implement-the-Octopus-Methodology.pdf",
            "Name": "5_WhitePaper_How-to-implement-the-Octopus-Methodology.pdf",
            "Type": "application/pdf",
            "Size": 2845068,
            "Abstract_en": "Octopus Methodology",
            "Description_en": "White Paper Series (5/6): How to implement the Octopus Methodology",
            "Comment": null
        },
        {
            "ID_CAT": 4,
            "ID_CAT_Parent": 2,
            "CategoryPath": "Documentation > KnowledgeRiver > White Paper",
            "ID_FIL": 6,
            "FilePath": "/home/Octopus/Files/uploads/6_WhitePaper_How-to-analyze-data-collected-with-the-Octopus-Methodology.pdf",
            "Name": "6_WhitePaper_How-to-analyze-data-collected-with-the-Octopus-Methodology.pdf",
            "Type": "application/pdf",
            "Size": 606461,
            "Abstract_en": "Data Analysis",
            "Description_en": "White Paper Series (6/6): How to analyze data collected with the Octopus Methodology",
            "Comment": null
        }
    ],
```

`ID_CAT` & `ID_CAT_Parent` needs to be used for tree and CategoryPath for depth or to extract the level label.

I've tried may examples from web but most of are with static data in different format or just simple render without table.

*Final outcome like this needed*
[image: Final outcome like this needed]

mat-tree, mat-table with dynamic data not possible